# Flow router Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm new with this framework. I want to use flow router as it is reactive. Before this I'm using iron router. Please someone show me how to change the code to flow router as flow router has no waitOn concept and onBeforeAction(replaced by triggersEnter). Your help and kindness really appreciated.

router.js

```
Router.route('/EditLokasi/:_id', {
    name: 'EditLokasi',
    template: 'EditLokasi',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
    var lokasiID = Lokasi.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    this.render('EditLokasi',{data: lokasiID});      
    },
    waitOn: function(){
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            var userid = Meteor.user().username;
            return [ Meteor.subscribe('profiles', userid), Meteor.subscribe('login') ];
        }
    }
});
```

EditLokasi.js

```
Template.EditLokasi.helpers({
    lokasi: function(){
        return Lokasi.find({data:lokasiID});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subscriptions` to [subscribe](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#subscription-management) and then, on the template, check if the data is [ready](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutersubsready-with-a-callback) through `subReady`

```
FlowRouter.route('/login', {
    name: 'login',
    subscriptions: function() {
       var userid = Meteor.user().username;
       this.register('subscribe-to-profile',  Meteor.subscribe('profiles', userid));
       // do it the same for other subscribe

    },
    action(params) {
       var lokasiID = Lokasi.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
       BlazeLayout.render('EditLokasi', {data: lokasiID});
    }
});
```

And on your template

```
<template name="EditLokasi">
 {{# if helper_checkSubReady}}
 ......
 {{else}}
 loading....
 {{/if}}
</template>
```

`helper_checkSubReady` is a helper to check if the subscriptions are ready or not (check the link I mentioned above)

Comment: I'm stuck at this code for a week. Can you suggest solution based on my code?